# Netezza 7.1: Backing out an Organize On clause on a large Fact Table

Tags: netezza

We implemented an Organize On clause on a large (40bn row) fact table in Netezza. All the documentation and blogs indicate that when you do this, "nothing happens" until you run a Groom on the table.

However, even before running the first groom we experienced a dramatic rise in Disk Read and Disk Write for inserts and updates to the table.

We decided to back out the change while we work on re-architecting the insert and update processes.

The IBM Netezza System Administrator’s Guide says "You can add to, change, or drop the organizing keys for a table by using ALTER TABLE. The additional or changed keys take effect immediately, but you must
groom the table to reorganize the records to the new keys." However, I cannot find the syntax to drop the organizing keys.

Our Technical Account Manager is looking into it and I'll update with any progress.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove columns from the organize clause on the table, simply specify an empty organize on clause like so:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME ORGANIZE ON NONE;
```

While it is true that the CBT organization of the table does not kick in until you request a GROOM, the system does immediately start tracking zonemap information for column types that it wouldn't otherwise (e.g. varchar).  So if you had added those sorts of columns to the ORGANIZE clause that will start collecting data immediately, even without a GROOM.

Comment: Thanks very much ScottMcG. No, it was two integer columns that we organized on. Our Technical Account Manager came back with the same empty organize on clause and said that he expected another groom would be needed to complete the change. He said colleagues are surprised to see any effect from Organize On prior to groom. However, we definitely observed it. So we are still trying to work out what caused it.